# MySQL: I have two tables, 1 production and 1 archive. I need to select distinct records from both as some records are identical

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, left-join, union

I have a MySQL database containing 2 tables.  `prod` is an in-production and `archive` has archived records. The columns are exactly the same.  `prod` does not have all records in `archive`.

I need to access distinct records in 1 join of the two tables so I'm not duplicating records and throwing calculations off in excel.

```
SELECT
    a.order_no,
    a.date_of_sale,
    a.cost,
    b.order_no,
    b.date_of_sale,
    b.cost

FROM
    `prod` AS a
    LEFT JOIN `archive` AS b ON a.order_no = b.order_no
```

Results:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
| order_no | date_of_sale | cost | order_no(1) | date_of_sale(2) | cost(2) |
+----------+--------------+------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
|      333 | 11-28-2017   |   10 |         333 | 11-28-2017      |      10 |
|      334 | 11-28-2017   |   12 |         334 | 11-28-2017      |      12 |
|      336 | 11-29-2017   |   30 |         335 | 11-28-2017      |      25 |
|      337 | 11-30-2017   |   15 |             |                 |         |
|      338 | 11-30-2017   |   17 |         338 | 11-28-2017      |      17 |
+----------+--------------+------+-------------+-----------------+---------+
```

How can I structure my query to filter records that are the same in both tables?

The result I'd like:

````
+----------+--------------+------+
| order_no | date_of_sale | cost |
+----------+--------------+------+
|      333 | 11-28-2017   |   10 |
|      334 | 11-28-2017   |   12 |
|      335 | 11-28-2017   |   25 |
|      336 | 11-29-2017   |   30 |
|      337 | 11-30-2017   |   15 |
|      338 | 11-30-2017   |   17 |
+----------+--------------+------+```
````

Comment: Please show us the result that you want.

Comment: Did you try to 'GROUP BY' the columns by their names?

Comment: How is the desired result different from what's just in `prod`?

Comment: @Barmar - thank you for pointing that out.  I changed the table information to show the difference and the desired result.

Comment: How is your original query joining `order_no = 336` in prod with `order_no = 335` in archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *suspect* that you want `union` rather than a `join`:

```
select order_no, date_of_sale, cost from prod
union 
select order_no, date_of_sale, cost from archive
```

`union` removes duplicates between the resultsets (and within the resultsets as well).

Comment: Union was perfect for this situation.  Never used it before.  Thank you!